# table with duplicate id inner join table no duplicate id

Tags: sql, join

in the last select result i see duplicate id . how to remove please the duplicate . see the attached picture

[3 select query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OB2Bb.png)

Comment: Column `CUSTOMER_SERVICE_TELEPHONE_NUM` is missing in your input data

Comment: Table A, Table B,...? Please clarify your issue

Comment: hi, every body the issue: how to make inner join without duplicate on TELEPHINE_NUM(FIRST ROW MATCH TAKED)

Comment: `SELECT DISTINCT`?

Comment: Hi josh ,the distinct is not work because i have multiple  column need to select and group by .you can provide or help in this query?

Comment: @OmarNaoushi : as of now your sample data is not talkative enough for us to provide a solution. You say you have multiple columns to select, but you are only showing one (which is why someone suggested to use DISTINCT). You would need to put more effort into preparing a data set and result to illustrate your question.

Comment: the issue one of table before join is contain duplicate customer id, after the join customer id repeat with same data as row, i need use top 1 to get only the first customer id if we have duplicate

Comment: even the subquery is not work when i used top 1

Comment: what is your definition of "duplicate" if DISTINCT is not the answer? In case of having multiple rows for same ID and different data in some column, which row would be selected? If any, then you could use group by and min(), or Max() for other columns.

Comment: Please clarify via post edits, not comments. Please give a [mcve]. PS "return one row no duplicate in customer_id" is unclear. Return which row? Which columns?

Comment: Please use text, not images/links, for text, including tables & ERDs. Textual content in images/links cannot be searched for & cannot be cut & pasted.

Answer (score 0):

While your sample data does not allow a 100% accurate answer, here are some guidelines that will hopefully help you.

To avoid duplicates in a join when no column can be used to uniquely identify the duplicate records, I would suggest to suppress them in a subquery, and then join the subquery with the other table.

As you seem to have *true* duplicates, meaning all columns that you retrive from the child table have identical values, then `DISTINCT` should to the trick :

```
SELECT i.*, c.TELEPHONE_NUM
FROM [dbo].[GT_Import] AS i
JOIN (
    SELECT DISTINCT TELEPHONE_NUM
    FROM [dbo].[ComplainSubscriber_Import]
) AS c ON c.TELEPHONE_NUM = i.TELEPHONE_NUM
WHERE ...
```

You can add more columns to the subquery, as long as they do have duplicated values.

Comment: hi GBM thx for reply even the question is not clear plz see the attached pic. i tried to replace the top by distinct but is same issue